# Redis max-active configuration value for SpringBoot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I have implement redis for a Spring boot application.

What value should I have to enter for below configuration in application.properties?

```
# <!-- Maximum active connections to Redis instance -->
spring.redis.pool.max-active=8
```

It was by default 8 in the documentation.

Then, I set it to 1 and test with multiple invocations which hits redis repo. Although I am expect a error saying, redis connections are not available, I did not get any error.

What am I missing here?

**Update question:**

As mp911de mentioned below, I have add @Transactional in my rest controller method and keep the thread wait for 10s.

> When using Spring Data Redis with enabled @Transactional, the
>   connection is bound from the first Redis access until the transaction
>   is committed/rolled back.

I have set spring.redis.pool.max-active to 1 and then invoke another rest api method which use redis while first rest invocation is still wait. So in this case, I am suppose to get connection not available exception right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### In Short

It depends on what you're planning to do.

### Explanation

A good value is 50% to 100% of the number of maximal concurrent requests within your application. The Redis connection is leased only for the duration of Redis operations in non-transactional mode.

You need to have `commons-pool2` on your classpath the pooling setting to take effect.  Earlier versions of Jedis/Spring Boot did not require `commons-pool2`.

When using Spring Data Redis with enabled `@Transactional`, the connection is bound from the first Redis access until the transaction is committed/rolled back.

If the number of max concurrent Threads seems unreasonably high and you don't use transactions/blocking operations, then you might want to take a look on the [lettuce driver](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:connectors:lettuce) integration. lettuce requires only one connection but it comes at the cost of more dependencies, and you need to configure the `RedisConnectionFactory` on your own.

Comment: I actually did not had commons-pool2 libraries as dependencies. In that case what is the default value of spring.redis.pool.max-active ?

Comment: No pooling? No pooling!

Comment: Actually I do have commons-pool2 available by spring-boot-starter-redis dependency artifact. Can you please see my update question section and give your answer

Comment: I thought Redis doesn't have rollback.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't missing anything, really - mp911de did a good job of explaining that. The max active limit just limits the number of connections that can be active at the same time - all other request threads will be blocked until a connection is made available.

As for the max number of connections you should allow - that really depends on your use case and on your Redis server. But generally, for RDBMS systems (and Redis shouldn't be that much different) around 20 is a reasonable limit - refer to [this link](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing) for further explanations. You should never set a big limit in advance, though. Always substantiate your decisions with load and performance tests.

Comment: The RDBMS comparison isn't applicable. Redis is a primarily in-memory store. Reading data happens in-memory only, so there's no spindle count (HDD) to consider. Writes _could_ affect disk access but in almost all cases, they don't because I/O is async and data is written to memory first.

Comment: I'd say that's a gross overstatement since it really depends on how big your data set is - for most databases, Redis or RDBMS, your data set can easily fit in memory, especially seeing how affordable machines with lots of RAM are. So the read performance should be comparable (granted, Redis will usually have different use cases and therefore faster read access but not by several orders of magnitude). Also, HDD spindle count? Really? :)

Comment: A HDD can do only one thing at a time and the Hikari CP guide contains a formula how to determine a pool size (backed by PostgreSQL) so that was my starting point why you can't compare Redis with traditional RDBMS, https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing#the-formula

Comment: Yes, but that formula is insanely obsolete - who uses HDDs any more? If you paid attention, the article states that SSDs have the opposite logic behind them - you should decrease the number of connections, not increase. That's basically the reason I mentioned that article - everything they said there more or less applies to Redis, too.